# About OnRenderImage Function in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i am trying to use OnRenderImge function in Unity. I succeed when i open 3D project. But when i use HD Renderer Pipeline project, the fucnction is not working. Is function delivered or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

They are removed when using HD Render Pipeline. The four functions below are *not* called when using HD Render Pipeline:

- OnPreCull
- OnPreRender
- OnPostRender
- OnRenderImage

The reason why they are removed are listed on [Unity's forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/feedback-wanted-scriptable-render-pipelines.470095/page-8):

As these callbacks stand they offer ways to inject extra rendering code into Unity. The issue that arises when attempting to port these to SRP world is multifaceted.

- Existing plugins that use these are built with a very very deep
  implicit contract with Unity

  - Assuming Camera.main is set
  - Current render target setup is ‘known’ pre call
  - You are using the legacy post processing (c++, little script control)
- Invoked by high level unity

  - Callbacks (generally) have no arguments

    - What camera is being used etc
  - Designed as a ‘primitive’ injection method

    - We have SRP where you can do much more
- These were invoked mid camera render. This was generally bad as we
  would have some rendering state configured and user code would then
  mutate this state (by calling a nested render, of just smashing some
  framebuffer state). This is where a large number of bugs in our
  backlog come from. The tough part is that fixing any bug here
  normally results in regressions against implicit, non documented
  behaviour.
- Always invoked, even if you don’t want or need them Overhead for no
  reason

---

**What to use when using HD Render Pipeline?**

Register to the `RenderPipeline.beginCameraRendering` and `RenderPipeline.beginFrameRendering` events. These are new experimental functions and can change anytime.

```
void OnEnable()
{
    RenderPipeline.beginCameraRendering += BeginCameraRendering;
    RenderPipeline.beginFrameRendering += BeginFrameRendering;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    RenderPipeline.beginCameraRendering -= BeginCameraRendering;
    RenderPipeline.beginFrameRendering -= BeginFrameRendering;
}

void BeginCameraRendering(Camera camera)
{

}

void BeginFrameRendering(Camera[] cameras)
{

}
```

Comment: the API has been modified a little bit. In recent versions of HDRP or URP, you can access it through "RenderPipelineManager.beginCameraRendering/beginFrameRendering".